# How to run Run only a Single test in Visual Studio Code and Python with output

Tags: python, testing, visual-studio-code, test-explorer

Does anyone know how to run only one python test with Test Explorer in Visual Studio Code?

I have installed https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=LittleFoxTeam.vscode-python-test-adapter.

I am using pytest.

In the picture below:

[image]

If I press "Run Test" then only one test runs, but I do not see any log / output.

To see the output I have to press "Run", but this runs all my tests. This is incredibly frustrating.

I would like to be able to run only the one test with the Visual Studio Code interface and see the log for this run.

Comment: FYI there is a [test explorer built into the Python extension for VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/testing) so you don't' necessarily need that extension.

Regardless, output will be in the Output Panel (in the Python extension it will be under the "Python Test Log" channel if I remember correctly).

Answer (score 5):

I did not find one elegant way to just run one test and then see the correct sampled/collected output from that test, but I found a way to run only the test I was working on by tagging it with:

```
@pytest.mark.run_this_test
```

and hit F5 anywhere in VSCode to just run this test over and over again. The PyTest debug config looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "PyTest",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "console": "integratedTerminal",
    "module": "pytest",
    "args": [
        "-s", "-m run_this_test"
    ],
    "justMyCode": false,
    "pythonPath": "${config:python.pythonPath}",
    "env": {
        "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceRoot}"
}
```

This 'tagging' does not scale in a team obviously, but it works for me alone.

I created a repo containing my solution: https://bitbucket.org/geircode/vscode-testsetup-python

To test it:

- run the script "requirements.install.bat"
- open vscode in the root folder
- select "PyTest" in the "debug and run" tab
- Hit F5 to start debugging and see the correct output from the test

Comment: In addition to above, to get the debugger to attach, I had to add "--no-cov" to the args...  
`"args": ["--no-cov","-m run_this_test"],`

Answer (score 3):

Check the Output Panel for output (look under the View menu if you're unfamiliar with it). There's probably a channel there where test output is sent (e.g. for the Python extension for VS Code it creates a "Python Test Log" channel for all test output).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

From VS Code test explorer it's possible. Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: When I click on the "Debug Test" icon you have circled, the test runs but the break points don't work. When I click on the Play/Run button just to the left of the debug button you circled ALL the tests run. I can see the output from ALL the tests in Output -> Python Test log. I have restarted VSCode. VSCode and extensions are all latest version.